# Why would a well pump have two pressure switches?

Tags: plumbing

Recently bought a house where the water pressure drops fairly low.  Looking at the pump pressure gauge, pump switches on at 20 and off at 60 psi.  So it would seem the fix is to decrease the differential to 40-60 except that the differential adjustment is already as loose as it can go.  (Tightening the off-center nut only increases the differential.) My next step is to replace the pump switch but there are actually two installed and I have no idea why.  Can I just replace these two with one or is there some other way I can fix the pressure?  As far as I can tell the second switch doesn't actually do anything.  I don't see it switching on/off at all and adjusting the nut doesn't have an effect.
[image: two pump switches]

Comment: How are the switches wired?

Comment: In series? but not really sure.

Comment: Become sure, and edit the question. It's difficult to speculate "why" (your question) without knowing how things are connected/arranged.

Comment: You need to trace the wiring to see if they are wired in series, parallel or controlling something totally different.

Comment: No,   One nut is range, the other is limit.

Answer (score 0):

Not to discourage you from checking, because you should, but an uncommon (for residential) use of a second switch like that is as backup protection against the main switch failing and over pressurizing the tank.